# C# beginner needs help fahrtocel

Tags: c#

I am totally new in coding world. I managed to write a code but something is still missing.
I try to run this program but it doesn't work as it should when I try to write a new temperature. here is my code

```
using System;

namespace Bastun1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static double FahrToCel(int fahr)
        {
            double cel = (fahr - 32) * 5 / 9;
            return cel;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double celsius;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Fahrenheit temperature: ");
            double fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) *5 / 9;
            
            Console.WriteLine("the converted Celsius temperature is: " + celsius);
            Console.WriteLine("Please press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadLine();       
            do
            {           
                if (celsius > 77)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("WARNING!! " + celsius + " too hot! turn down the temperature");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                if (celsius < 73)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(celsius +  " NOT READY YET. Turn up the temperature");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else if (celsius == 75)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Perfect temperature! Enjoy");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77);
            Console.WriteLine(" It is " + celsius + " .Perfect temperature! Enjoy");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. What tells you it doesn't work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: Could you share what exactly is not working as expected? It crashes or the output is not correct and what is the output if so ?

Comment: Thnk you guys. it converts the temperature in the beginning, but it doesn't do that when the temperature is higher than 77 or lower that 73. something is missing.

Comment: @FoYa An important first step to programming is learning how to debug your code. Your first step should be to set a breakpoint and step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: Step through your app line by line: when is it asking for a new temperature?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the assignment back into your variable `celsius`. Try to adjust to this:

```
do
{
    if (celsius > 77)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("WARNING!! " + celsius + " too hot! turn down the temperature");
        celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    if (celsius < 73)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(celsius + " NOT READY YET. Turn up the temperature");
        celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    else if (celsius == 75)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perfect temperature! Enjoy");
        celsius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
while (celsius < 73 || celsius > 77);
```

Also when you enter: e.g. '76'. It will not ask for a new number since you only cover > 77, < 73 or == 75.

Comment: Thank you Hendrik, it works but the temperature needs to be in Farh before it converts to cel.